# Reverse engineer firmware image and rebuild Linux kernel for TI-AR7

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, reverse-engineering, firmware

I am trying to build my own Linux derivative to run on an TI-AR7 board. I took the board from an old Telekom Speedport W 501V router. To understand how firmware is flashed onto the device I have downloaded the most recent [official firmware](https://www.telekom.de/hilfe/geraete-zubehoer/router/weitere-router/speedport-w-5xx-serie/speedport-w-501v?samChecked=true). Using the Linux `file` command I determined the image is a tar archive, which can be extracted easily.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse$ ls
fw_speedport_w501v_v_28.04.38.image
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse$ file fw*
fw_speedport_w501v_v_28.04.38.image: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse$ tar -xvf fw*
./var/
./var/tmp/
./var/tmp/kernel.image
./var/tmp/filesystem.image
./var/flash_update.ko
./var/flash_update.o
./var/info.txt
./var/install
./var/chksum
./var/regelex
./var/signature
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse$
```

According to a [wiki (Firmware-Image)](http://www.wehavemorefun.de/fritzbox/Firmware-Image) that I have found, `./var/tmp/kernel.image` contains the actual firmware. During the update process this image is written to the `mtd1` device. As stated in the [wiki (LZMA-Kernel)](http://www.wehavemorefun.de/fritzbox/LZMA-Kernel) the lzma compressed kernel starts with the magic number `0xfeed1281`. A hexdump of  `kernel.image` contains that number at its beginning.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ hexdump -n 4 kernel.image
0000000 1281 feed
0000004
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$
```

The following script given on the last wiki entry should decompress the kernel.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use Compress::unLZMA;
use Archive::Zip;

open INPUT, "<$ARGV[0]" or die "can't open $ARGV[0]: $!";

read INPUT, $buf, 4;
$magic = unpack("V", $buf);
if ($magic != 0xfeed1281) {
  die "bad magic";
}

read INPUT, $buf, 4;
$len = unpack("V", $buf);

read INPUT, $buf, 4*2; # address, unknown

read INPUT, $buf, 4;
$clen = unpack("V", $buf);
read INPUT, $buf, 4;
$dlen = unpack("V", $buf);
read INPUT, $buf, 4;
$cksum = unpack("V", $buf);
printf "Archive checksum: 0x%08x\n", $cksum;

read INPUT, $buf, 1+4; # properties, dictionary size
read INPUT, $dummy, 3; # alignment
$buf .= pack('VV', $dlen, 0); # 8 bytes of real size
#$buf .= pack('VV', -1, -1); # 8 bytes of real size
read INPUT, $buf2, $clen;

$crc = Archive::Zip::computeCRC32($buf2);
printf "Input CRC32: 0x%08x\n", $crc;
if ($cksum != $crc) {
  die "wrong checksum";
}
$buf .= $buf2;

$data = Compress::unLZMA::uncompress($buf);
unless (defined $data) {
  die "uncompress: $@";
}

open OUTPUT, ">$ARGV[1]" or die "can't write $ARGV[1]";
print OUTPUT $data;
#truncate OUTPUT, $dlen;
```

To use the script you may need to install [Compress::unLZMA](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Compress-unLZMA-0.04/lib/Compress/unLZMA.pm) and [Archive::Zip](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Archive-Zip-1.56/lib/Archive/Zip.pm) perl modules.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ tar -xvf Compress*
Compress-unLZMA-0.04/
Compress-unLZMA-0.04/Makefile.PL
Compress-unLZMA-0.04/ppport.h
Compress-unLZMA-0.04/Changes
Compress-unLZMA-0.04/lzma_sdk/
[...]
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ cd Compress*
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp/Compress-unLZMA-0.04$ perl Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Compress::unLZMA
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp/Compress-unLZMA-0.04$ make
cp lib/Compress/unLZMA.pm blib/lib/Compress/unLZMA.pm
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl/5.18/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl/5.18/ExtUtils/typemap  unLZMA.xs > unLZMA.xsc && mv unLZMA.xsc unLZMA.c
cc -c  -I. -Ilzma_sdk/Source -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE
[...]
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp/Compress-unLZMA-0.04$ sudo make install
Files found in blib/arch: installing files in blib/lib into architecture dependent library tree
Installing /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/auto/Compress/unLZMA/unLZMA.bs
Installing /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/auto/Compress/unLZMA/unLZMA.so
Installing /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/Compress/unLZMA.pm
Installing /usr/local/man/man3/Compress::unLZMA.3pm
Appending installation info to /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/perllocal.pod
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp/Compress-unLZMA-0.04$ # same for Archive::Zip module
```

After installing these dependencies the script decompressed the kernel successfully.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ ./decompress.pl kernel.image kernel.decompressed
Archive checksum: 0x29176e12
Input CRC32: 0x29176e12
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$
```

But what kind of file is `kernel.decompressed` and how do I generate a similar file from my Linux kernel source? I continued analyzing it using `file` and [binwalk](https://github.com/devttys0/binwalk).

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ file kernel.decompressed
kernel.decompressed: data
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ binwalk kernel.decompressed

DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1509632       0x170900        Linux kernel version "2.6.13.1-ohio (686) (gcc version 3.4.6) #9 Wed Apr 4 13:48:08 CEST 2007"
1516240       0x1722D0        CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
1517535       0x1727DF        Copyright string: "Copyright 1995-1998 Mark Adler "
1549488       0x17A4B0        Unix path: /usr/gnemul/irix/
1550920       0x17AA48        Unix path: /usr/lib/libc.so.1
1618031       0x18B06F        Neighborly text, "neighbor %.2x%.2x.%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x:%.2x lost on port %d(%s)(%s)"
1966080       0x1E0000        gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 2007-04-04 11:45:13

ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$
```

So the Linux kernel starts at `1509632` and ends at `1516240`. What kind of data is stored in front the Linux kernel (`0` to `1509632`)? I extracted the kernel and that piece of unknown data using `dd`.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ dd if=kernel.decompressed of=unknown.data bs=1 count=1509632
1509632+0 records in
1509632+0 records out
1509632 bytes (1.5 MB) copied, 1.62137 s, 931 kB/s
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ dd if=kernel.decompressed of=kernel bs=1 skip=1509632 count=6608
6608+0 records in
6608+0 records out
6608 bytes (6.6 kB) copied, 0.0072771 s, 908 kB/s
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$
```

I need to ask again: What kind of file is `kernel` and how do I generate a similar file from my Linux kernel source? I used `xxd` and `strings` to look at the file more closely.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ xxd -l 100 kernel
0000000: 4c69 6e75 7820 7665 7273 696f 6e20 322e  Linux version 2.
0000010: 362e 3133 2e31 2d6f 6869 6f20 2836 3836  6.13.1-ohio (686
0000020: 2920 2867 6363 2076 6572 7369 6f6e 2033  ) (gcc version 3
0000030: 2e34 2e36 2920 2339 2057 6564 2041 7072  .4.6) #9 Wed Apr
0000040: 2034 2031 333a 3438 3a30 3820 4345 5354   4 13:48:08 CEST
0000050: 2032 3030 370a 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   2007...........
0000060: 0000 0000                                ....
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$ strings kernel
Linux version 2.6.13.1-ohio (686) (gcc version 3.4.6) #9 Wed Apr 4 13:48:08 CEST 2007
do_be
do_bp
do_tr
do_ri
do_cpu
nmi_exception_handler
do_ade
emulate_load_store_insn
do_page_fault
context_switch
__put_task_struct
do_exit
local_bh_enable
run_workqueue
2.6.13.1-ohio gcc-3.4
enable_irq
__free_pages_ok
free_hot_cold_page
prep_new_page
kmem_cache_destroy
kmem_cache_create
pageout
vunmap_pte_range
vmap_pte_range
__vunmap
__brelse
sync_dirty_buffer
bio_endio
queue_kicked_iocb
proc_get_inode
remove_proc_entry
sysfs_get
sysfs_fill_super
kref_get
kref_put
0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
vsnprintf
{zt^f
pw0Gm
0cIZ-
68BG+
QC]S%
v,;Zk
ubuntu@ip-172-31-23-210:~/reverse/var/tmp$
```

This Github [repository](https://github.com/leon1101/laughing-parakeet) contains the extracted files to use for further analysis.

Comment: What do you see when you run `xxd -l 1000 kernel` ( more than 100), Given your extensive research, I assume you have done that, isn't there anything of interest near the "top" of the file? (I don't know anything about kernel development, so just interested, rather than able to help ;-) ). Great Q, bye the way. Good luck.

Comment: I [uploaded](https://github.com/leon1101/laughing-parakeet/blob/master/var/tmp/kernel.hexdump) the whole hexdump, which is quite short. Compared to the ```vmlinuz``` file of my computer it contains many strings and repeated bytes like ```00```, which makes me wonder wether ```kernel``` is the file I am really looking for.

Comment: If the kernel image is created from GPLv2 code why not to ask vendor to provide you sources?

Comment: I've already got the code, but it is incomplete and does therefore not compile successfully. I was interested in reverse engineering and thought it would be easier in my case, but I will now try to rework that ```Makefile-mess```.

Comment: your question is really long....it is not useful as a question at all.   respect everyone's time, and shorten your question, if u want to provide more details, write it into your blog pages.